# What HTTP status code is appropriate when a client attempts to update a data entity that is stale on the client-side?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-response-codes

I've built an API where the client will instruct the server to update some entity in the database, and it must accommodate multiple users attempting to operate on the same data entitity, possibly at the 'same time'.

This is a distributed users race condition problem. (Similar to how Wordpress handles "Locking" of blog posts as other users are editing them.)

**An Example Data Entity**

```
{
    versionID : 12345,
    type : "building",
    name : "The CN Tower"
}
```

**Operating on a Data Entity**

For example, the client will tell the server to `update` the `name` property of any given entity.

In order to handle multiple users trying to change the same entity — without the users accidentally overwriting each other's updates — each user must send along with its `update` request the `versionID` (also possibly known as a `stateID`) of the database entity it got it from server when it was loaded into the UI (or otherwise stored on the client-side in the case of CLI apps).

This way, if `Client A` has updated the building before `Client B`, the server will be able to tell `Client B` that their update request has failed because the building they're trying to update is not the current (canonical) state of such record in the database.

**The Question**

What is the proper http [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) from the server when any user attempts to update a database record that has already been updated by another user in the interim?

Comment: @Opal Good question. What do you think now?

Answer (score 10):

I think the API should respond with [409 Conflict Error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10), whilst including the latest state of the resource (building, in your case) in the body that helps identify the latest version to the consumer.

Comment: Having looked at the W3 spec and compared to the question from Opal, this is the correct answer (and code). 412 looks to be thrown if headers are being checked and that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

In such case the server should reply with [`412 Precondition Failed`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.13) status code.

It typically works with the following headers (send along with the request):

- ETag
- If-Modified-Since
- If-Not-Modified-Since

Server checks the value of one the headers mentioned above and if *it matches* to client is allowed to modify the resource, otherwise `412` should be returned.

So `A` wants to edit `C` with `ETag` equal to `10`. Server accepts this request, edits `C` computes new `ETag` e.g. `11` and sends the resource back. Now, if `B` wants to edit `C` with `ETag` equal to `10` it will receive 412. `B` should synchronize the resource `C` and try to edit it once again.